# Is there a limited light waves emission rate?

Tags: visible-light

Is there?

I mean, say, the sun emits light waves towards us and those waves travel through vacuum at the speed of light, or `c`. But does the sun emit those waves in every given moment? Or maybe, just maybe, the sun emits waves every certain fraction of a second, say every `10^-40` (just a random fraction) seconds a wave is emitted from the sun. Does the sun really ALWAYS emit waves? Or just in unnoticeable amounts of time? Is there any way to even test it? And if the emission rate is limited, is it equal with every light source?

Do we know of one? Do we know that such one doesn't exist? Is it even possible to know any of these?

Comment: This will be hard to answer satisfactorily if you are thinking that "the sun" is one big object instead of a mindbogglingly large number of particles.

Comment: @Asher Of course not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to measure it. Someone would've figured out a long time ago.

But asides from that: No, that's not how it works. Google or Wikipedia "black-body radiation" and keep an eye out for whatever magic you imagine to be at play, here.

Besides, if I already mentioned black body radiation: This had to work on all wavelengths which means that it'd be even easier to figure it out using something colder and would be really obvious there.

And I don't think you picked 10^-40 randomly but tried to find something "close" to the Planck time. Let me tell you, no matter what mainstream bullshit media is telling you, our universe is not pixelated. This is something made up by people who have no idea what they're talking about. Our universe is not defined on small scales. This has nothing to do with pixelation, totally different things.

Comment: It's a nice reading over black-body radiation. I did pick a measure a bit close to the Planck time but it had nothing to actually do with the pixelated universe bullshit, I was just curious. More about the way it could've been measured in. But yes, as you said and mentioned, it constantly emits electromagnetic radiation as longs as its temperature is above the absolute zero. Thank you for your answer